# How to adapt the AdderNet CNN for 1D input sequence processing?

Tags: neural-network, conv-neural-network, conv1d

The original AdderNet CNN is designed for processing images which are 2 Dimensional (https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.13200) (Github - https://github.com/huawei-noah/AdderNet). I would like to change the architecture of the AdderNet to process 1 dimensional inputs. However, the size of matrices are not completely aligned in my case. Therefore the performance is poor. Can you help me figure out where is the misalignment in my case?

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import numpy as np
from torch.autograd import Function
import math

def adder1d_function(X, W, stride=1, padding=0):
    n_filters, d_filter, w_filter = W.size()
    n_x, d_x, w_x = X.size() # not changing thrg the process
    w_out = (w_x - w_filter + 2 * padding) // stride + 1
    w_out = int(w_out)
    X_col = torch.nn.functional.unfold(X.view(1, -1, w_x), (1,w_filter), dilation=1, padding=padding, stride=stride).view(n_x, -1, w_out)
    X_col = X_col.permute(1,2,0).contiguous().view(X_col.size(1),-1)
    W_col = W.view(n_filters, -1) # n_filters independent

    out = adder.apply(W_col,X_col)
    out = out.view(n_filters, w_out, n_x)
    out = out.permute(2, 0, 1).contiguous()
    
    return out


class adder(Function):
    @staticmethod
    def forward(ctx, W_col, X_col):
        ctx.save_for_backward(W_col,X_col)
        output = -(W_col.unsqueeze(2)-X_col.unsqueeze(0)).abs().sum(1)
        return output

    @staticmethod
    def backward(ctx,grad_output):
        W_col,X_col = ctx.saved_tensors
        grad_W_col = ((X_col.unsqueeze(0)-W_col.unsqueeze(2))*grad_output.unsqueeze(1)).sum(2)
        grad_W_col = grad_W_col/grad_W_col.norm(p=2).clamp(min=1e-12)*math.sqrt(W_col.size(1)*W_col.size(0))/5
        grad_X_col = (-(X_col.unsqueeze(0)-W_col.unsqueeze(2)).clamp(-1,1)*grad_output.unsqueeze(1)).sum(0)
        return grad_W_col, grad_X_col


class adder1d(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self,input_channel,output_channel,kernel_size, stride=1, padding=0, bias = False):
        super(adder1d, self).__init__()
        self.stride = stride
        self.padding = padding
        self.input_channel = input_channel
        self.output_channel = output_channel
        self.kernel_size = kernel_size
        self.adder = torch.nn.Parameter(nn.init.xavier_normal_(torch.randn(output_channel,input_channel,kernel_size))) # delete here kernel_size dim
        self.bias = bias
        if bias:
            self.b = torch.nn.Parameter(nn.init.uniform_(torch.zeros(output_channel)))

    def forward(self, x):
        output = adder1d_function(x,self.adder, self.stride, self.padding)
        if self.bias:
            output += self.b.unsqueeze(0).unsqueeze(2)#.unsqueeze(3)
        
        return output
```

The inputs are of size torch.Size([131070, 1, 5]). Thank you.

The code is adapted to read and process the 1D sequence, but the performance is very bad.